# Getting error about bad escape during start of Arelle

Tags: python, ubuntu, lxml, ubuntu-18.04, arelle

I am trying to get Arelle working on Ubuntu linux 18.04 with Python 3.6.9.

**Step-1: (Download Arelle software):**

git clone https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle.git -b lxml

**Step-2 Install Python LXML:**

apt-get install -y python-lxml

**Step-3 Install Python tk:**

Due to error: 'No module named tkinter'

...I install:

apt-get install python3-tk

---

When it's time to start Arelle from terminal, I use:

```
python3 arelleGUI.pyw
```

I then get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arelleGUI.pyw", line 9, in <module>
    from arelle import CntlrWinMain
  File "/tmp3/Arelle/arelle/CntlrWinMain.py", line 22, in <module>
    from arelle import Cntlr
  File "/tmp3/Arelle/arelle/Cntlr.py", line 8, in <module>
    from arelle import ModelManager
  File "/tmp3/Arelle/arelle/ModelManager.py", line 8, in <module>
    from arelle import (ModelXbrl, Validate, DisclosureSystem)
  File "/tmp3/Arelle/arelle/Validate.py", line 9, in <module>
    from arelle import (ModelXbrl, ModelVersReport, XbrlConst, ModelDocument,
  File "/tmp3/Arelle/arelle/ModelVersReport.py", line 9, in <module>
    from arelle import (XbrlConst, XbrlUtil, XmlUtil, UrlUtil, ModelXbrl, ModelDocument, ModelVersObject)
  File "/tmp3/Arelle/arelle/ModelDocument.py", line 9, in <module>
    from arelle import (XbrlConst, XmlUtil, UrlUtil, ValidateFilingText, XmlValidate)
  File "/tmp3/Arelle/arelle/ValidateFilingText.py", line 16, in <module>
    docCheckPattern = re.compile(r"&\w+;|[^0-9A-Za-z`~!@#$%&\*\(\)\.\-+ \[\]\{\}\|\\:;\"'<>,_?/=\t\n\r\m\f]") # won't match &#nnn;
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 527, in _parse
    code1 = _class_escape(source, this)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 336, in _class_escape
    raise source.error('bad escape %s' % escape, len(escape))
sre_constants.error: bad escape \m at position 67
```

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141820/how-to-resolve-python-regex-error-error-bad-escape-m-at-position-37-when-pas) that seems related to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in Arelle, which shows up for Python 3.6 and later. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/pull/73) for it , but that is still open (since July 2017). Given that Python 3.6 has been out for quite a while, I don't know why this hasn't been fixed.

You are using the `lxml` branch, which has been [stale for 10 years](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/branches). So perhaps this error has actually been fixed (even if the pull request is still open) on the master brach, but not on the `lxml` branch. Try installing from master first, if that is an option for you.