# How to avoid re.sub processing backslashes in replacement string in python 3.10.5?

Tags: python

I'm running into an (<class 're.error'>, error('bad escape \S at position 51'), <traceback object at 0x00000230E5F63580>) when trying to use re.sub

My code is probably a mess, because I started to learn Python a week a go. It runs through certain (xml) files in a given source folder, copy a part of the file based on a regex, and paste it into a file with the same name in a given target folder, replacing the existing part based on the same regex. It works fine, but as soon as the replacement string contains \S (which can happen, because it is a path), the replacement fails.

Here is my code (sorry for the mess):

```
import re
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog

source_input = simpledialog.askstring(title="Quelldateien", prompt="Pfad zu den Quelldateien:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t")
target_input = simpledialog.askstring(title="Zieldateien", prompt="Pfad zu den Zieldateien:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t")
search_pattern = re.compile("<reference>.*?</reference>", re.DOTALL)

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_input):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".sdlxliff"):
            source_file = open(path + os.sep + filename, 'r', encoding="utf8")
            source_content = source_file.read()
            source_file.close()
            source_reference = re.search(search_pattern, source_content)
            source_reference_string = source_reference.group(0)

            target_path = path.replace(source_input, target_input)
            if os.path.exists(target_path + os.sep + filename):
                target_file = open(target_path + os.sep + filename, 'r', encoding="utf8")
                target_content = target_file.read()
                target_file.close()

                newdata = re.sub(search_pattern, source_reference_string, target_content)

                target_file = open(target_path + os.sep + filename, 'w', encoding="utf8")
                target_file.write(newdata)
                target_file.close()

messagebox.showinfo(title="Erledigt", message="Der Referenzteil wurde ersetzt.")
```

The replacement string in re.sub (source_reference_string variable) looks like this:

```
<reference><external-file href="file://C:\\_Projekte\\S$$$\\220909_error_ZV\\en-US\\$$$$ - Kopie.pptx" uid="Pptx.DependencyFileId"/></reference>
```

I found this thread and tried to replace re with regex, but I ran into the same error:
[Python 3.7.4: 're.error: bad escape \s at position 0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328587/python-3-7-4-re-error-bad-escape-s-at-position-0)

I would like re.sub to just take the replacement string without interpreting any backslashes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `search_pattern` is already a regex, you want `search_pattern.sub(source_reference_string, target_content)`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the quick answer. I replaced `re.sub(search_pattern, source_reference_string, target_content)` with `search_pattern.sub(source_reference_string, target_content)`. However, that doesn't change the root cause: the \S in `source_reference_string` still causes the bad escape error

Comment: Yeah, that's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of `re.sub` the repl argument can be a string or a function. if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. You could pass a lambda function there just return your string without any processing of backslashes.

```
newdata = re.sub(search_pattern, lambda _: source_reference_string, target_content)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. I didn't know that you can create a function so easily.

Comment: haha, genius!!!